# SwiftUI - Menu looks different in toolbar and normal view

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI application for MacOS, and I want to creata a menu button. I have got the general functionality working, however, what puzzles me is that it looks different depending on where I place it. I have the menu button in the toolbar, and in another view I have a similar button, but in a "normal" (non-toolbar) view.

In the toolbar it looks exactly like I want it to look, but in my other view it looks more like a dropdown menu (specifically the arrow part).

This is the code for the menu in the toolbar:

```
ZStack{
    // Rest of view
}.toolbar {
    Menu {
        Button(action: {
            //Action code
        }) {
            Text("Open File")
        }
        Button(action: {
            //Action code
        }) {
            Text("Open URL")
        }
    } label: {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
            Text("Open")
        }
    }.menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle())
}
```

This is how it looks, and how I want it to look:

[image: Toolbar menu button]

I have essentialy the same SwiftUI code for my other button:

```
HStack{
    // Other components
    Menu {
        Button(action: {
            //Action code
        }) {
            Text("Open File")
        }
        Button(action: {
            //Action code
        }) {
            Text("Open URL")
        }
    } label: {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
            Text("Open")
        }
    }.menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle())
}
```

And this is how it looks there:

[image]

Is there any way to have the same look in a plain view as in the toolbar? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.menuStyle` instead of `.menuButtonStyle` (which is deprecated).

I found that it then removed the border too, but you can add your own:

```swift
Menu {
    // content as before
} label: {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
        Text("Open")
    }
}
.menuStyle(.borderlessButton)
.padding(6)
.background {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
        .stroke(.gray)
}
```